# Bootstrap - navigation + sub nav shows and hides on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, tabs, nav

I am trying to  make navigation that would have similar effect to dropdown but instead of box with sub menu it will show tabs. I made it and it works just fine - the only problem I have is that the sub menu will show when I click on the button (which is fine) but it wont close when I click on it again. So what I want to make is: click on button - sub menu shows - click on same button again and sub menu hides.

```
<!-- Navigation bar -->
        <div class="container-narrow">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main">
            <li class="nav-size active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-size"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-size"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="nav-size"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><img src="img/flags/flags12.png" alt="flags" /></a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-sub">
                                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Site Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">O'Leary Group</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-sub">
                                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/en.png" /> English</a></li>
                                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/fr.png" /> French</a></a></li>
                                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/de.png" /> German</a></a></li>
                                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/pl.png" /> Polish</a></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
      </div><!-- / Navigation bar -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be worth investigating the [collapse plugin](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse). You can make it work by doing the following

```
<!-- Navigation bar -->
<div class="container-narrow">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main">
        <li class="nav-size active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-size"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tab1">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-size"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-size"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><img src="img/flags/flags12.png" alt="flags" /></a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="collapse" id="tab1">
        <div class="tab-pane" >
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-sub">
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Site Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">O'Leary Group</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-sub">
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/en.png" /> English</a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/fr.png" /> French</a></a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/de.png" /> German</a></a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/pl.png" /> Polish</a></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- / Navigation bar -->
```

It's not perfect, but It doesn't seem as though tabs will present the behaviour you require OOTB.